# Cómo establecer una relación many-to-many en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, tablas, relaciones

Tengo una duda al desarrollar relaciones de tablas con laravel. Tengo una tabla "artículos", esta tabla debe ir relacionada con dos tablas "colores" y "tallas".

El problema esta en que se debe establecer la cantidad de ese articulo que hay en inventario separando cuantos de cada color y cuantos de cada talla.

No se si crear una tabla llamada "cantidad_disponible" o alguna otra tabla que me guarde la relación de las cantidades con los colores y las cantidades con las tallas. Agradecería un poco de ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto puedo controlar los movimientos que deseas.

**opcion 2**

Este modelo esta basado en control de inventario entre articulo-color y articulo-talla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este tendrás la información del total generalizado que se maneja del articulo, y aparte del total en su articulo-color y articulo-talla

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo, el problema de tu desarrollo es el mismo al que ya yo había llegado. La cantidad de un articulo se debe presentar con dos distribuciones, la de colores y la de tallas. Entonces colocar una tabla con el campo "cantidad" no me ayudara de nada. Debe ser "cantidad respecto a los colores" y "cantidad respecto a tallas"

Comment: según lo que entendí, edite un nuevo modelo.

Comment: Realizando esta alternativa, llegue al resultado correcto!

Comment: Que bueno estimado, espero poder seguir ayudando en lo que pueda.

Answer (score 2):

Parece ser que tu problema no es de laravel, parece ser que tienes un problema de diseño de bases de datos. Normalmente cuando se quiere realizar una relación muchos a muchos `(n a n)` entre dos entidades (o tablas) se crea una entidad débil de por medio con `foráneas` a sus respectivas tablas, entonces de esta manera si quieres que un artículo pueda tener muchas tallas, colores y viceversa, puedes crear una tabla `Inventario_tallas` e `Inventario_colores` con los atributos o columnas:

```
Inventario_tallas

cod_articulo | cod_talla | cantidad_inventario|
```

Donde `cod_articulo` es foránea a `artículo` y `cod_talla` es foránea a `talla`

```
Inventario_colores

cod_articulo | cod_color | cantidad_inventario|
```

Donde `cod_articulo` es foránea a artículo y `cod_color` es foránea a color

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, lo intentare!

Comment: Que bueno que intentes mi respuesta. No sé por qué recibió un voto negativo, pero bueno, hay gente que le gusta dejar votos negativos sin explicación alguna. La respuesta de arriba también es buena pero no se ajusta a lo que dijiste, ya que recalcaste que querías un inventario de tallas separado a un inventario de colores. La respuesta de arriba lo hace con una tabla en vez de dos, esa es la diferencia

Comment: Avísame si también necesitas un diagrama entidad relación como el de arriba, con gusto la edito

Comment: Perfecto, lo aplicare y te aviso si lo necesito. Gracias de antemano!